# Unable to format microSD card

Tags: partitioning, formatting, gparted, micro-sd-card

I have a SanDisk Ultra microSD card with 16 GB capacity.I connected it to my laptop using a Zebronics ZEB-230CR card reader.

I am facing issues with formatting the card.
I opened the Disks utility on Ubuntu 18.04 and formatted the whole drive to msdos layout. Disks utility shows that the drive has 16 GB unallocated space.
GParted also shows the same. 
However when I add a FAT32 partition using GParted I get the following error:

> Can't have a partition outside the disk!

The output of fdisk /dev/sdb -l is as follows:

[fdisk ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV4tE.png)

I am unable to diagnose the problem from any previous answers. The partition fails to be created correctly. Is this an issue with the sd card or am I doing something wrong?

edit:
After formatting the disk using the "Disks" utility the output of fdisk is as follows
[after formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCRR6.png)

edit:
Logs after attempting to create a partition

> Blockquote
>   GParted 0.30.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize
>
> Libparted 3.2
>
> Create Primary Partition #1 (fat32, 14.84 GiB) on /dev/sdb  00:00:05    ( ERROR )
>
> create empty partition  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
>
> path: /dev/sdb1 (partition)
>   start: 2048
>   end: 31115263
>   size: 31113216 (14.84 GiB)
>   clear old file system signatures in /dev/sdb1  00:00:05    ( ERROR )
>   libparted messages    ( INFO )
>
> ## Can't have a partition outside the disk!

Comment: That is a strange partition table. Do you always get the same thing when using _Disks_?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it multiple times and get the same thing.

Comment: Can you try using either fdisk's `o` command or GParted's "Device → Create partition table" command, both to create a blank DOS partition table?

Comment: Your SD is not partitioned and it cannot have partitions now, it is like a diskette (or like a partittion on HDD). You can only format it into a filesystem which you need. Or you must re-partition it, create MBR on it, and then you can create partitions... but I do not recommend.

Comment: gnome-disks' "Format disk" does usually create a partition table. (Not to be confused with "Format partition" which initializes a filesystem.) @GautamRamakrishnan: Can you show screenshots of the format options that you have selected?

Comment: I used "Do not overwrite existing data" and "Compatible with all systems and Devices" options

Comment: That should be fine then. What results do you get from re-creating the partition table via GParted or fdisk?

Comment: The image under the link "fdisk ouput" is shown after re-creating the partition table via GParted. I am creating a FAT32 partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally a fresh partition table shouldn't have any entries visible at all – even though it always has exactly 4 slots, they should be zeroed out and wouldn't appear in partitioning tools. That is, after creating one partition via fdisk, one partition is what you should see.

But in your screenshots, the remaining partition table entries aren't zeroed out – although their *type* is set to "Empty", the entries still have start/size and other values present. (Additionally, the first partition is ~31 GB even though it's on a ~15 GB disk, and no partitioning tool would have allowed this.)

This is probably *not* a software bug – the repeating pattern `0x0200'0200` (33554944) in all 'start' and 'size' fields makes me suspect it's a hardware problem (e.g. the card's flash memory going bad). Basically, even though the program tries to write zeros to the card, some bits are permanently stuck at '1' after reading the same data back.

(That's also why the first partition's start sector 2048 (0x0000'0800) suddenly becomes 33556992 (0x0200'0A00), and most likely the entire MBR is corrupted the same way.)

Try a different card on the same reader, and try the same card on a different reader – one of them probably needs to be thrown away. (Maybe clean the electrical contacts just in case?)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll test it out and let you know.

Comment: Looks like the reader may be bad. I reformatted the micro SD card on my phone without any hassles. I'll check the reader once.